# Install twitter web app if I declined the first time

Tags: 12.04, unity, firefox, webapps

I was going to install twitter web app so it could integrate with unity, but I missclicked (yeah what a dumbass) and declined to do so. Now I have refreshed the page several times, and the alert with the suggestion doesn't appear....

Any way to force that firefox behavior???

thanks in advance.